# JSP and Servlets: pass parameters using hyperlink, is it possible?

Tags: jsp, hyperlink

I want to create two hyperlinks, side by side: Reply and Delete.
I can, of-course, do it like this

```
<form action="MyServlet" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="Reply" value="Reply">
    <input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete">
</form>
```

and then figure out in MyServlet which button was clicked with `request.getParameter("name_of_the_input_button")` however, I don't want buttons, but hyperlinks.
I want something like that:

```
<a href="MyServlet">Reply<a>
<a href="MyServlet">Delete<a>
```

problem is, I can't pass parameters this way, and I have no way to figure out what was picked...
I even tried hidden buttons but that didn't work out for me...
Is it possible to pass parameters with hyperlink somehow? 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode the parameter into the URLs the hyperlinks reference. In other words, add the [Query String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) part to them:

```
<a href="MyServlet?name_of_the_input_button=Reply">Reply<a>
<a href="MyServlet?name_of_the_input_button=Delete">Delete<a>
```